# Selenium with VB.NET - Cannot find element

Tags: css, vb.net, selenium, xpath

I'm new to Selenium, and I've stumbled upon an error.

I'm trying to download a specific file from a website(seen in code), when I get to the last section of the website where the download link becomes available, I'm having trouble selecting the 'Download Full Securities List'. I've tried with XPath CSS Selectors and so on.

Could any of you tech-savvy guys out there kindly suggest a fix/recommendation?

Any help would be great!

Thank you,
Cihan

```
Sub downloadDBX()
    'Initalise Chrome Browser For Execution
    Dim driver As IWebDriver
    driver = New ChromeDriver("C:\Users\cihan\Documents\Selenium")

    'Navigate to the DBx Website
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://etf.deutscheam.com/GBR/ENG/Disclaimer/Institutional")

    'Get ElementID to navigate DBX Website
    Dim agreeTerms As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='form']/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a"))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    agreeTerms.Click()

    'Navigate to the equities section of DBx
    Dim equitiesPage As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='form']/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/span[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a"))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    equitiesPage.Click()

    'click relevant fund
    Dim myFundInformation As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("ATX UCITS ETF (DR)"))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    myFundInformation.Click()

    'change to "ETF Information tab" to gather required data
    Dim myFundHoldings As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl02_ctl15_ctl00_ctl01_126']/span"))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    myFundHoldings.Click()


    'download my holdings
    Dim myData As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl02_ctl15_ctl00_container']div[2]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/a/div[2]/span"))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    myData.Click()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was solved by searching for the link text rather than the XPATH of the download link. Before and after as follows:

```
'download my holdings
Dim myData As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl02_ctl15_ctl00_container']div[2]/div[3]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/a/div[2]/span"))
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
myData.Click()
```

now:

```
    'download my holdings
    Dim myData As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Download Full Securities List"))
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    myData.Click()
```